# SQL: ORDER BY, AND, WHERE returns boolean error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Trying just to order some ids by the date if their status is not active (aktiv = nei) and if its less then 7 days ago they where created, but i'm getting the "**mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given**" error, and I can't seem to figure out why.

I'm following the general order of caluses (SELECT,FROM,WHERE,GROUP BY,HAVING,ORDER BY). It works if i remove ORDRE BY or the date selection.

```
$aktivnei = 'SELECT * FROM `test3` WHERE aktiv LIKE "Nei" AND datex BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE(); ORDER BY datex DESC';
$resultaktivnei = mysqli_query($conn,$aktivnei);

<?php
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultaktivnei)) {
    echo '<li class="list-group-item">'.$row['id'].' / '.strftime('%H:%M, %e.%b',strtotime($row['datex'])).'</li>';
  };
?>
```

I have also tried this, but getting the exact same error. I have also tried moving the caluses around but to no success.

```
$aktivnei = 'SELECT * FROM `test3`';
$aktivnei .= ' WHERE aktiv LIKE "Nei" AND datex BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE();';
$aktivnei .= ' ORDER BY datex DESC';
```

It's probably dead simple, but right now i'm just scratching my head after trying so many different things.

Comment: You have a semicolon before the `ORDER BY`.  I consider this a typo and vote to close such questions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Yeah. Stupid me to not see something that simple. Also voted to close it, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove semicolon before `order by`

```
'SELECT * FROM `test3` WHERE aktiv LIKE "Nei" AND datex BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY datex DESC'
```